# withLatestFrom not returning

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I have the following effect

```
  @Effect()
  createMission$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<featureActions.CreateMissionRequest>(featureActions.ActionTypes.CreateMissionRequest),
    withLatestFrom(this.store$),
    map(([action, state]) => {
      return this.dataService.createMission(state.missions.entities[action.payload.routeId])).pipe(
        map(response => new featureActions.CreateMissionSuccess({response, mission: state.missions.entities[action.payload.routeId]})),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          return of(new featureActions.CreateMissionFailed({error}));
        }),
      );
    }),
  );
```

Instead of manipulating the store, I have a selector in my code like this =>

```
export const featureAdapter: EntityAdapter<IMissionRoute> = createEntityAdapter<IMissionRoute>({
  selectId: model => model.routeId,
});
export const selectAllEntities: (state: object) => Dictionary<IMissionRoute> = featureAdapter.getSelectors(selectMissionState).selectEntities;


export const getById = () => createSelector(
  selectAllEntities,
  (entities, props) => entities[props.id]
);
```

I would like to use it in the withLatestFrom

```
    withLatestFrom((action) => this.store$.pipe(select(MissionsStoreSelectors.getById(), {id : action.payload.routeId}))),
    map(([action, mission]) => {
          /// 
     }
```

The problem I face is, if I do the later implementation, I will not have 2 observable( one for action one for mission) but only a single one.

I do not understand what to change to make it work

Comment: do you have a working minimal example you can share? Also, why do you need the action for the latter implementation. Can you just use the mission object to call your dataService?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you need the action in your @Effect, now that you moved the mission select logic to the selector.

SOmething like this should/may work (untested code below).

e.g.

```
 @Effect()
  createMission$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<featureActions.CreateMissionRequest>(featureActions.ActionTypes.CreateMissionRequest),
    withLatestFrom((action) => this.store$.pipe(select(MissionsStoreSelectors.getById(), {id : action.payload.routeId}))),
    map(_mission => {
      return this.dataService.createMission(_mission).pipe(
        map(response => new featureActions.CreateMissionSuccess({response, mission: _mission})),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          return of(new featureActions.CreateMissionFailed({error}));
        }),
      );
    }),
  );
```

Comment: but _mission is an observable in the map.

Comment: Did you try it? I didn't change the flow of your code, cause you were just asking about not having an `action`input in the map function. I am just showing you how to remove.

Comment: yes I tried, but I fixed it in a similar way.

the method you show return an observable from withlatest, and is not of the type I want,

Comment: maybe if you can supply a working fiddle or stackblitz I can help more effectively.

Comment: you probably will, but it s ok dont worry thanks ^^